# About installing the open cv library

Tags: opencv, installation

sir,

I have tried my level best to install open cv library 2.2.0 version.but it has'nt suceeded
it shows that errors in linking the library hughigh,
whether we wanted to insatll the ipp library prior to install the opencv?
please help me ?..............

Comment: it would be useful to get more information about the steps you have taken.

Answer (score 0):

I can only recommend the install advice on the OpenCV page. If you are using a unix download the source of the library you want to install and then use cmake to install the library. That usually works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the 1.1 version of OpenCV.

The 2.x version is brand new and as of Nov 1 2009 you will have difficulty finding documentation for that. The 1.1 version of OpenCV, on the other hand, is very well documented and you should have no trouble finding online tutorials for your platform that walk you  through the installation process step-by-step.

As an aside: "IPP" refers to Intel's Performance Primitives. In the 1.1 version these are entirely optional. OpenCV does not require them. If you have the Performance Primitives installed, however, your OpenCV code may run faster. (For me it cut down my image processing time by a factor of five.) Once you get everything up and running you can purchase the IPP library from intel here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp/